# What is the area enclosed by the $y$ axis of the graphs $y = 3\cos(x)$ and $y = x$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I set up the integral $\int{(3\cos x-x)}\mathrm dx$. I found the limits to plug in $3\sin(x) - \frac{x^2}{2}$ by setting the two functions equal to each other which were $x= 1.17$ and $x=-2.93$, however I got the question wrong. My answer was $x=-2.21$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are told to find the area enclosed by the region $y=3\cos(x)$, $y=x$ and the y-axis (i.e $x=0$). This means that your limits of integration are incorrect. 
Instead, the integral should be $$\int _0^{1.17}\left(3cos\left(x\right)-x\right)dx\: \approx 2.08$$

Answer (score 0):

Your bounds are wrong. Try from $x=0$ to $x=1.17$.